# How get user E-mail with Login Facebook on Android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I used this sample to connect Login on Android with Facebook(https://github.com/RajivManivannan/Android-Social-Login), when I run in Android device, the sample give me the user email and other informations .But in my app when I use return above example, it just return User name and ID.

```
{Response:  responseCode: 200, graphObject: {"name":"User Name","id":"123456789321654987"}, error: null}
```

This import the SDK: compile `'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.1'`

I think the problem is the app in Facebook configuration at my, but I cant figure it out. My app only returns **name and id**.

The app has on Facebook Console Approved Items:

> email, public_profile and user_friends.

I tested with different e-mail ids, but it gives the same result.

How I can get the email?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for help with the question @tauqir and thanks for all answers!  The samples was changed and now my app works too! Was add this codeon request task: ' Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
//Explicitly we need to specify the fields to get values else some values will be null.
parameters.putString("fields", "id,birthday,email,first_name,gender,last_name,link,location,name");
request.setParameters(parameters);'

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you are listed as a developer in your FB app settings from the Facebook developers console. And that the correct key hash is there. Also, be sure you are requesting the email permission in the me request.

Unless Facebook has approved your app for the extended email permission you will not be able to access certain data, like an email address, for anyone except people you've registered as Admins, developers, or testers in the Facebook Developer console.

Answer (score 0):

Have you included email in permissions when request?

ie:

```
List<String> permissions = Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email", "user_friends");
```

and then call:

```
public void logInWithReadPermissions(Activity activity, Collection permissions)
```

with your permissions.

here is then docs from facebook:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/LoginManager/

Comment: My app use the equals permissions e this method to call login and brink just name and id from user logged in facebook by the login button. I think the problem is the app in Facebook Console, but cant find error. thanks

Answer (score 0):

FacebookCallback does not provide user email.

You have to use  GraphRequest.newMeRequest(..) in this way

```
   val request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(facebookLoginresult.accessToken) { 
                 fbJSONObject: JSONObject?, _: GraphResponse? ->
                 //your code 
            }

        val parameters = Bundle()
        parameters.putString("fields", "first_name,last_name,email")
        request.parameters = parameters
        request.executeAsync()
```